# Votos de usuários como funcionam?

Tags: debate, votos

Como funciona o sistema de votos de utilizadores: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters?

Para que servem?

Como são atribuídos o número de votos por utilizador?

O que diferencia do [meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters) para o [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Como funciona o sistema de votos de utilizadores: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters?

Essa aba mostra um ranking ordenado por votantes, ou seja, quem deu mais votos aparece mais alto no ranking.

Os votos considerados são apenas os votos dados em publicações (perguntas e respostas), não tem nada a ver com votos em comentários, eleições, filas de análise nem nada disso.

> Para que servem?

Para saber quem deu mais votos.

> Como são atribuídos o número de votos por utilizador?

Quando você vota a favor ou contra alguma publicação esse voto é contabilizado.

> O que diferencia do [meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters) para o [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters)?

Ambos sites possuem tal ranking (assim como você já havia linkado na sua pergunta), e o sistema funciona igual para os dois.

A diferença é que lá contabiliza os votos que você deu lá. Aqui contabiliza os votos que você deu aqui.

Comment: Math eu pensei que isso tinha a ver com votos para cada um utilizar em votações, por exemplo eleger um moderador. Isso são os *upvotes* e os *downvotes* certo?

Comment: @JorgeB. exato! Já que eu não deixei totalmente claro vou editar então;

Comment: Math, está ótimo, eu é que pensei que era uma coisa totalmente diferente. Nem me passou pela cabeça outra coisa. Deve ser por ser inicio de semana ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. sem problemas ;)